# Can't upload files with PHP

Tags: php, upload, warnings

i am going to use a simple php script to upload images to the specified folder but i got this error after sending file:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpbY8z4A' to 'http://www.yapi-dekorasyon.net/images/Exactly-Sport-According-to-Zodiac.jpg' in /home/pyapitj2/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 8
```

Upload failed

```
Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
[userfile] => Array
    (
        [name] => Exactly-Sport-According-to-Zodiac.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpbY8z4A
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 119217
    )

)
```

index.php;

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

upload.php;

```
$uploaddir = 'http://www.yapi-dekorasyon.net/images/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo "<p>";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
echo "Upload failed";
}

echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
```

As i tried many other scripts for uploading files to the site i got similar errors. How to solve this problem?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to upload the file to a URL folder, instead of a Path such as /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/uploads/

Comment: i have changed to path to: /var/www/vhosts/yapi-dekorasyon.net/httpdocs/images and i got this error now: Warning: move_uploaded_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/yapi-dekorasyon.net/httpdocs/images/burclarin-zayif-yonleri.jpg) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/pyapitj2:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/pyapitj2/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 8

Comment: Looks like the path should actually be /home/pyapitj2/public_html/images

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a server problem instead of script?